# How can I use NSFetchedResultsController and custom sections?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

My app has a list of schedules.

- Section 1: Doctor
- Section 2: Personal
- Section 3: Expired schedules

I'm currently using `sectionNameKeyPath:@"source"`, which is either doctor or personal, problem is the expired section. This can be determined by an `endDate` attribute in that same entity.

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                        sectionNameKeyPath:@"source" cacheName:@"Root"];
```

So how can I keep using `NSFetchedResultsController` but somehow use these three sections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your data model, make a new transient attribute on your Schedule entity, called "sectionName". Then write a method on your Schedule class `-(NSString*)sectionName`, to return the correct string. Finally use `@"sectionName"` as the section name key path for your fetched results controller.

Don't forget that in your fetch request, the items have to be already sorted into the right order to be grouped into sections — that's a requirement of the NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: So in order to move expired entries to the expired section, I need to change the attribute in the entity on viewDidLoad before I create the NSFetchedResultsController?